# Datastructure with two indices

Tags: java, android, data-structures

I'm working on a system where I look up an object with either of two different index systems. So I wonder which data structure to use for this?

The actual case: I scan either an RFID tag or a QR code, and it belongs to a certain list of)files. So each list of files has both an RFID and a QR code, and I can use whichever to look it up. How can I best build this as an object?

Example of the data:

```
RFID | QR | Files
-----+----+----------
001  | abc| file1_french.txt, file1_english.txt
002  | def| file2_french.txt, file2_english.txt
003  | ghi| file3_french.txt, file3_english.txt
```

Should I just have two hashmaps with the different indeces? I'm a bit confused, I don't even know how to look for an answer to this problem.

Comment: One question since I'm unsure if I got it right. RFID/QR can have list of files (where list is 1..n) and every file has only 1 RFID/QR?

Comment: I made an edit to clarify

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maintain an array of objects. Create two HashMaps where:

```
HashMap<RFID, index>;
Hashmap<QRCODE,index>
```

where index is the Index Of object In Array, so you don't need to keep two references for the objects, instead you can use the index value, and use it to access from the array.

Comment: Ah that makes sense indeed.

Comment: Seeing you can have multiple files for an index, you can store it in a list,something like this: `HashMap<RFID, ArrayList<Integers>>`

Comment: The list of files part is not the problem, that can just be some kind of object that contains the files. It was more about the indeces.

Answer (score 1):

You already have the solution in hand :D First HashMap with RFID as the key, and the second with QR code as the key. You then reference to the objects as you seems fit. You will then have two HashMap with the same size.

Comment: Thanks. It just felt a bit weird to have two separate lists. For example if I make a mistake and have one file not exist in one of the two lists it could cause strange problems. So a single structure would have been cool to find.